# how to add image view with some constraints programmatically using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am new in iOS Development. If using storyboard, I can place an Image view in view controller like this

[image]

I need to make something like that programmatically.

so I have custom view from a library called `RevealingSplashView` , but I need to add an image view to that custom UI View. I just know to add the image view, maybe something like this

```
let imageName = "yourImage.png"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
revealingSplashView.addSubview(imageView)
```

but I don't know how to set that constraint to image view to

a. align to center x to superview

b. proportional width to superview 0.8

c. height constraint = 25

d. align bottom to safe area = 32

how to do that ?

here is the code I use before want to add image view

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
            let iconWidth = (screenSize.width) * 0.8
            let iconHeight = iconWidth * 1 // ratio 1:1
            revealingSplashView = RevealingSplashView(iconImage: UIImage(named: "Loading Page Asset")!,iconInitialSize: CGSize(width: iconWidth, height: iconHeight), backgroundColor: AppColor.mainYellow.getUIColor())
            revealingSplashView.animationType = SplashAnimationType.twitter
            revealingSplashView.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill


            // add loading indicator to RevealingSplashView Programatically
            revealingSplashViewIndicator.color = UIColor.white
            revealingSplashViewIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
            revealingSplashViewIndicator.center =  CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y + (iconHeight/2) + 64 )
            revealingSplashView.addSubview(revealingSplashViewIndicator)
            revealingSplashViewIndicator.bringSubviewToFront(self.revealingSplashView)
            revealingSplashViewIndicator.startAnimating()

            let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
            window?.addSubview(revealingSplashView)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using anchors:

```
let imageName = "yourImage.png"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
revealingSplashView.addSubview(imageView)

// you need to turn off autoresizing masks (storyboards do this automatically)
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// setup constraints, it is recommended to activate them through `NSLayoutConstraint.activate`
// instead of `constraint.isActive = true` because of performance reasons
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: revealingSplashView.centerXAnchor),
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: revealingSplashView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25),
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: revealingSplashView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
    ])
```

Comment: unfortunately it makes crash to my app: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x283c9b7c0 "UIImageView:0x104057cd0.bottom"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x283c36e40 "UILayoutGuide:0x281e48620'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

Comment: @Alexa289 you have to add `revealingSplashView` as a subview of the `self.view` before activating constraints.. so make sure somewhere before adding those constraints you call `self.view.addSubview(revealingSplashView)`

Comment: @Alexa289 I have updated the answer.. if there is something else you have in mind regarding the view hierarchy why this is not possible, I suggest you update the question to reflect that

Comment: I have tried to add your code like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiexP.png , it is no longer crash, but I don't know why the image shows in the top of the screen like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eepT.jpg

Comment: @Alexa289 did you set up constraints for the `revealingSplashView`? it has to have constraints too.. I assumed you already did that.. update the question to show how you want to constrain the `revealingSplashView`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192620/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-alexa289).

Comment: Ok, I have added when I add revealingsplash view in my VC

Answer (score 1):

To add constraints programmatically you need to set

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

then you can set the constraints:

```
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: revealingSplashView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

if you want to activate constraints you need to set

```
isActive = true
```

also if you support iOS < 11 you need to put a control because you don't have the safeArea

Comment: unfortunately it makes crash to my app, error message: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutDimension:0x280d18f80 "UIImageView:0x10483ad70.width"> and <NSLayoutDimension:0x280d18cc0 "RevealingSplashView.RevealingSplashView:0x1048648d0.width"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

Comment: did you added `revealingSplashView` to your view?

Answer (score 0):

```
revealingSplashView.addSubview(imageView)

imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: revealingSplashView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: revealingSplashView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```